# Setting a maximum size for vertical windows in vim

Tags: ide, editor, vim

When working with split windows, I often make use of the command to size all windows equally. However, I also use mini buffer explorer in a vertical window, which I want to keep to a maximum width of 25. Is there any way I can configure vim so that either the mini buffer explorer window does not get re-sized or it stays at a maximum width of 25?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do

```
:set winfixwidth
```

in the window that you want to stay the same.

See

```
:help winfixheight
:help winfixwidth
```

Comment: Thanks! Actually this problem has troubled me for a quite a long time. In order to make mini buffer explorer have fixed height every time the vim is started, one just need to add the line of "set winfixheight" at line 701 of plugin/minibufexpl.vim, before the line of "call <SID>DEBUG('Completed StartExplorer()'  ,10)".

Answer (score 1):

Here is a part of `minibufexpl.vim`:

```
"               If you would like a vertical explorer you can assign the column
"               width (in characters) you want for your explorer window with the
"               following .vimrc variable (this was introduced in 6.3.0):
"
"                 let g:miniBufExplVSplit = 20   " column width in chars
"
"               IN HORIZONTAL MODE:
"               It is now (as of 6.1.1) possible to set a maximum height for
"               the -MiniBufExplorer- window. You can set the max height by
"               letting the following variable in your .vimrc:
"
"                 let g:miniBufExplMaxSize = <max lines: defualt 0>
"               
"               setting this to 0 will mean the window gets as big as
"               needed to fit all your buffers.
```

This should help to solve your problem.